# Can a white-haired witch grapple multiple targets?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, witch

The [white-haired witch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/archetypes/paizo---witch-archetypes/white-haired-witch) needs to spend a standard action to maintain the [grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) at the beginning of the next round, if she succeeded in hitting (and thus grappling) a target, and the target failed to break free. - But what if an Attack of Opportunity is provoked before her next round? Can more of her hair (eyebrows?) stretch out and attack? With combat reflexes and high dexterity, at high levels she'd be threatening a large area. What if she hit say 3 enemies (1 on her turn and then 2 AOs since), all now grappled (while she's still not in the grappled condition), now it's her turn again. Her spending a standard action to maintain the grapple, would that be for all 3 or just the one she grappled on her turn? Or would each new grapple end the old one?

> "When a white-haired witch grapples a foe in this way, she does not gain the grappled condition."

I can't see anything RAW keeping her from grappling more people.

Answer (score 9):

**You can grapple multiple targets, but only until your turn.**

Looking at the rules, I see nothing that disagrees with your idea that the witch can start extra grapples with her hair using attacks of opportunity while she grapples someone else.  As you note, it takes a standard action to *keep* someone grappled, which means that unless you find a way of generating extra standard actions, you can only keep one opponent grappled once it's your turn.  The others go free.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst there is nothing in RAW keeping her from grappling more people the rules for grappling are fairly comprehensive, including rules for multiple opponents. The rules state several people can gang up to grapple one person, or can assist a defender being grappled to break free, but there are no rules about one person grappling multiple people.

Whilst this is my opinion, because there is nothing in RAW that I can find, if I was your DM, I would rule that all of your available hair was being used to grapple the opponent and that although you do not gain the grappled condition, whilst grappling someone with your hair you cannot make an attack of opportunity with your hair. You can still attack with something else.

I would also rule that the only way you could grapple multiple people is to have one grappled by your hair, and a second grappled by you. The second would cause you to gain the grappled condition.

Whilst none of that is in RAW, I cannot find anything in RAW to state how it should be ruled **either way** and as such it comes down to your DM to make a ruling on how to handle it (unless someone more observant than me can find something). This is quite obscure though, so I think you'll have to go with common sense.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the hair is magickal and regrows instantly, I really can't see any built in restriction about dividing it into as many strands as you want. Obviously you can't maintain more than one grapple but you can impede many people at once under the right circumstances.

This is quite important as for instance, with greater grapple, which makes maintaining a move action, you can then keep a person trapped as a move action with one strand of hair and attack them as a standard action with another.

This is effective and needs good design but is hardly overpowered.

Answer (score -1):

So, I can see two ways of making this work with multiple grapples while keeping yourself free of the grappled condition. 1. You take the greater grapple feat. This allows you to make 2 grapple checks in a round (one as a move action and the other as your standard). The second is being a tetori-monk and taking the feral training feat. This allows you to use any natural attack(your hair) with all the benefits of an unarmed strike (flurry of blows, replace an attack with a grapple. in either case, you are pretty much stuck where you stand, but it allows for more grapples.

Comment: I think the question is about understanding how the basic ability works in the first place, rather than how to achieve multiple hair-grapples otherwise.